# TV movie/miniseries that had frozen alien "gods" in a desert cave?

Tags: story-identification

I saw this as a kid, and I'm pretty sure it was on the Hallmark channel, but I can't find it.

I just remember it featured two alien humanoid beings described as gods. They were sitting on thrones, I think, and were frozen, but now defrosting for some reason. They were in a cave in a desert somewhere (Sahara?).

I'm pretty sure it was a miniseries because it was shown in two parts.

This was early 2000s.

Comment: When exactly did you see this?

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE! Feel free to take the [Science Fiction & Fantasy tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand our site better. You can also visit [How to ask a good question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) together with this [guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question/) and subsequently add more details to your question, so that it will be easier for others to find the TV series that you are searching for.

Comment: @Gallifreyan This was early 2000s. I'll add it to the post.

Answer (score 2):

Long shot, but could this be the movie "**The Queen of the Damned**", based on Anne Rice's novel? Does this image ring a bell? They weren't gods as such but ancient vampires who were treated as gods by their worshipers.

[image]

Later on they "defrosted", sort of.

[image]

Comment: I don't think that's it, but this really looks interesting in its own right. Will check out.

Comment: @OptimalSolver don't bother. 'Tis a rubbish movie.

Comment: @moriarty But the soundtrack is great!